# <form method="POST" class="form-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu164" action="app1.php" <!-- none box -->

Tags: php, html

using this code im not near and expert can you help seems like the php is not beig called and the txt is blank

```
<form method="POST" class="form-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu164" action="app1.php" <!-- none box -->
<div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu171" data-required="true" data-type="email"><!-- none box -->
 <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u174-4"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu171_input" name="Email" tabindex="1"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu171_prompt" for="widgetu171_input"><span class="actAsPara">Username</span></label></span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u175-4"><!-- content -->
 <p>Actualizando...</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u165-4"><!-- content -->
 <p>Correo inválido</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u176-4"><!-- content -->
 <p>Actualizado..!!</p>
</div>
<input name="-" type="submit" class="submit-btn NoWrap grpelem" id="u166-17" tabindex="3" value=""/>
<!-- state-based BG images -->
<div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu225" data-required="true"><!-- none box -->
 <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u227-4"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="password" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu225_input" name="custom_U225" tabindex="2"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu225_prompt" for="widgetu225_input" href=""><span class="actAsPara">Contraseña</span></label></span>
</div>
```

Comment: *seems like the php is not beig called and the txt is blank* could you describe the expected behavior of the code.. and the php code that is not called..? i'm not sure which txt you refers to also..

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` Tag doesnt close at the end. Missing `>` an missing `</form>`

Comment: Is there i dont know why is not posted